# JQUERY Mobile Database Results Retrieval List View

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, listview, mobile

I am trying to build a dynamic jquery mobile list view based off results from a database. I have the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('./Display.php?id=100');
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]></script>
```

and

`<div id="results"></div>`

Display.php has a while loop

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "{$row['title']}
    {$row['message']}
    {$row['datetime']}
    </br>
    ";              
}
```

At the moment this just outputs title, message and datetime on the .html and php pages but I want to use this with:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
            </a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a number of ways to get this working but it doesn't seem to, I have cleaned the while loop code up so its basic for this question. Has anyone managed to do this? Normally I would just run the `<li></li>` through a foreach but this is different. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building a listview, your results div should be a listview... not just a div.
So I suggest you place

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="results">
</ul>
```

instead of your

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

just for starters...
Then your php should echo the content of the ul. I mean something like this:

```
echo '<li><h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3><p><strong>'.$row['message'].'</strong></p></li>';
```

I did not test it but you should.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I sorted this months ago :D